# JQuery - How can i smoothly resize an image to create a pulsating effect?

Tags: jquery, image, resize, scale, effect

Hey, Im working on a website with a friend of mine, and from the start, our client has been unhappy with the quality of one of our animations. This animation takes an image and makes it larger, it then makes it smaller, and repeats to get a pulsating effect. The opacity also changes throughout the animation.

The current animation is on the home page of the site http://laveryrowe.com. The animation in question is the 75% image that you can see immediately upon arriving at the site.

I have tested in safari, firefox and internet explorer. The animation only just about makes the cut in firefox, however safari and internet explorer do not produce smooth enough resizes for our client.

Does anyone know of a better method of animating than the one i have used? (see code below and check out the site for an example).

```
function pulse() {
    $('#seventyfive').animate({
        marginTop: 175, 
        marginLeft: 25, 
        width: 261, height: 98, 
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 700, function() {
        $('#seventyfive').animate({
            marginTop: 161.95, 
            marginLeft: 15.2, 
            width: 287.1, height: 107.8, 
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            pulse();
        });
    }); 
};
```

Many thanks in advance, We could really use a hand,

> **Edit:** *The issue isn't with the positioning, (or at least i don't think it is) instead, its more to do with the way the image is resized, you can notice the jittery edges as it gets bigger. It seems to look better as the opacity is increased, but i need the same quality for when it is opaque.*

Jai

Comment: I think you should use css transition for browsers that support it (IE9, Firefox, Safari, Opera), and fallback to animated gif if it doesn't

Comment: Not to start a war, but I can see another side to that.  Why develop (test, deploy, maintain) two solutions where one will do?

Comment: 2 solutions does seem a little wasteful, but thanks anyway! my only issue with GIFs is that they can have a strange pixelated effect sometimes, or is that just my way of creating them?

Comment: I am using IE8 and I think it looks pretty smooth. In what way does it look bad? Is it a framerate thing or are the edges jagged looking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your animation isn't smooth because your marginLeft gets rounded down (image moves to the left one pixel) and then your width gets rounded up (image pixels are moved right just a little because they are re-sampled to a larger width.)  Even though the image didn't move right your eyes tell you that it did because they perceive the middle of the image as being slightly to the right.  This along with doing the same thing vertically makes the animation appear to jump around.

Here's an example of why I think the edges seem to flicker or shake.  Below Are two images both 3 by 1 pixels.  They are both resized to 5 by 1 and moved 4 pixels to the left.  The blue one is what you are seeing where the size and location change independently.  The red one only allows the size to change when the location changes and should appear to be a smooth animation.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info, but its not so much the positioning of the image (or at least thats not a major issue at the moment) thats the problem, more that the image itself has scrappy edges when its resized. as it gets bigger, it seems like the edges start to jitter.

Comment: @Jai I think we are talking about the same thing.  I view it as shaking but I guess that's the same idea as edge jitter.

Comment: i have a feeling its something more to do with the image itself, maybe because its not a good enough resolution, but if it is the margin and the width, would it work better if i was to round the integer values i have?

Comment: Integers as the starting and ending values wont help since jQuery.animate will divide them by time slices.  You would have to animate the position and then manually set the size as it's animating.

Comment: do you mean as in, run the animate as a sort of loop function? where the sizes are all set manually throughout the loop, so in essence if am somewhat defining the time slices myself?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using jQuery UI effects?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#default

Another alternative is to talk them out of the pulsing 75% and into some yellow blinking banners and the tasteful use of frames.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have indeed looked into them, unfortunately the scale effect seems to have the same problem as using animate. I wish very much that i could change the clients mind, but he's just not that kind of guy haha

Answer (score 2):

And what about animating the font size? I.e. => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/D3X7R/

js/jQuery

```
(function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').animate(
        {
            'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.5
        }, 700, function(){pulse(!back)});
})(false);
```

Markup:

```
<div id="seventyfive">75%</div>
```

Css:

```
#seventyfive{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i like the idea behind it, but the format of the 75% is crucial (according to our client) and so it needs to be an image rather than a particular font, which cannot be quite so specific.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using += some quantity instead of animating to a specific value each time. I've used it before and never noticed any problems.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure that would really make that much difference, and i prefer to work in precise measurements, that i can predict without having to think too hard haha

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's an example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4jLD/)

The problem is that you're animating both the position and the size at the same time and they're out of sync with each other.  I understand that you're doing this to try to keep it centered vertically and horizontally.  Instead, I would use a (*dreaded*) table to keep the image in the correct position and just pulse the size and opacity with Javascript, like so:

```
<table id="table75">
    <tr>
        <td><img id="seventyfive" src="http://laveryrowe.com/assets/images/heading_index_75.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

#table75 { width:XXXpx; height:YYYpx; }
#table75 tr { vertical-align:middle; }
#table75 tr td { text-align:center; }

function pulse() {
    $('#seventyfive').animate({
        width: 261, height: 98, 
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 700, function() {
        $('#seventyfive').animate({
            width: 287.1, height: 107.8, 
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            pulse();
        });
    }); 
};
```

You can position and size this table however you need to get it in the right place (using absolute positioning if necessary).

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4jLD/)

Comment: This appears to shake for me in chrome 12.

Comment: its producing pretty much the same as what i've already got in regard to the image quality, but i'll admit the movement is much smoother, so thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would use Flash to animate the "75%" PNG SUPER smooth with easing function. That will work very well.

Comment: OP specifically said he needs a jQuery answer. This doesn't help.